# Angular- How to create a pipe that converts milliseconds to hh:mm:ss format in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I want to create a pipe that converts milliseconds to hh:mm:ss format in angular. I read few articles but that didn't work for me.

pipe.ts:

```
transform(value) 
  {
    let formatted;

    let duration = moment.duration(value, "milliseconds");
    
    if(value < 59999){
      formatted = `00:00:${duration.format("hh:mm:ss")}`;
      
    }
    else if(value < 3599999){
      formatted = `00:${duration.format("hh:mm:ss")}`;
    }
    else {
      formatted = duration.format("hh:mm:ss");
    }
    return formatted;
```

error- I got wrong output like if i pass 23677258 milliseconds then i got 3:44:20 as an output which is wrong

Comment: You might wanna specify "didn't work for me". Errors? Wrong output?

Comment: Please try to elaborate on what you tried and what did not work.

Comment: Sorry the fault was mine, Now i correct my question and add specific error

Comment: In angular is wery easy convert miliseconds to hour with You example result with this metho is: 07:34:37 and this how convert mili to display hour: {{23677258 |date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}

Comment: yes i tried this now i got 08:36:35 for 23677258 milliseconds. The right time for this milliseconds is 6:34:37 which i checked in a online tool

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using moment.js, simply provide the value as a parameter to moment, and then specify the format you would like the result to be output to.

```
transform (value : number | string) : string {
  return moment(value).format('HH:mm:ss');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i´ts only for test purpose:

```
this.myTime = new Date(23677258);
    const zoneoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
    this.myTime = new Date(this.myTime.setHours(this.myTime.getUTCHours() - zoneoffset));
```

result for me is [image: zoneoffset]